# Get data from API using jquery

Tags: json, api, get

I really need your help, i cant get all data from this API: http://datahub.virk.dk/api/2/rest/package/smiley-kontrolrapporter

this is my code

```
<div class="mypanel"></div>

<script>
$.getJSON('http://datahub.virk.dk/api/2/rest/package/smiley-kontrolrapporter', function(data) {

    var text = `<h2>${data.license_title}</h2><br>
                <h2>${data.url}</h2><br>
                <h2>${data.url}</h2><br>
                <h2>${data.url}</h2><br>
                ${data.resources.description}`


    $(".mypanel").html(text);
});
</script>
```

please help me. thank you.

Comment: could you please see me the example to do that? i cant follow the link, i dont know how to read..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `url` is empty in that link. You most likely mean the `url` in the `resources` array items. But since it is an array you need to iterate or target the specific index you want. The same goes for the `description`. It is not part of the `resources`, it is part of each item in the `resources`.

Something like

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mypanel"></div>

<script>
  $.getJSON('http://datahub.virk.dk/api/2/rest/package/smiley-kontrolrapporter', function(data) {

    var resources = data.resources.map(resource => `<a href="${resource.url}">${resource.description}</a><br>`),
        text = `<h2>${data.license_title}</h2><br>
               ${resources.join('')}`;

    $(".mypanel").html(text);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, so it will be okay if i follow your code to the rest?

Comment: `  
    <i>Tags: ${data.tags}</i>
     <p><b>Organization description:</b>  ${data.organization.description}</p>
     <p><b>Organization title:</b>  ${data.organization.title}</p>
     <p><b>Organization created:</b>  ${data.organization.created}</p>
     <p><b>Organization Status:</b>  ${data.organization.approval_status}</p>
     <p><b>Name:</b>  ${data.name}</p>
     <p><b>Notes:</b> ${data.notes_rendered}
`
it looks like this?

Comment: Thanks, how about the last part sir? in ' extras ', i dont know how to do that.. and also i got '[HTML_REMOVED]'. how to fix that? this is my working links.. http://smiley.design4web.dk/api.html

Comment: @JorhendzStudios `extras` is a normal `object` so you access its properties with `data.extras.area_id` etc. ABout the HTML_REMOVED that is what is returned in the JSON so nothing to do about it unless the API can provide this somehow.

Comment: thank you.last quetion. Do you see the hidden data in that api? that need to encrypt? or thats the all data what i have right now? thank you.

Comment: Hi sir, i have a question, what is the problem in my codes? **_${data.extras.contact-name}_**
**_${data.extras.theme-primary}_** no display or output.. please help me. thanks

Comment: @JorhendzStudios when using the `.` notation you cannot have `-` in the property names. You should use `${data.extras['contact-name']}` and `${data.extras['theme-primary']}`